# Sticky entries in shell history

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, command-history

Is there a way one could make some commands "sticky" in a shell history?

I want to save some favourite commands that would be searchable with Ctrl+R, like the rest of the history, but they should never expire.

Comment: you've tagged bash and zsh; are you looking for something across shells, or for one in particular?

Comment: Anything, really :) It might be the killer feature that will convince me to switch back to bash.

Comment: I used to be very reliant on `Ctrl-R` and went to a lot of effort to ensure that my history was never over-written by multiple simultaneous sessions or lost after a crash. I eventually came to embrace aliases for storing favoured commands permanently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way is to put code in your shell startup file to read an additional history file, and make sure that you store sufficiently many history lines in memory so that the sticky lines aren't forgotten.

#### bash

In `~/.bashrc`:

```
history -r ~/.bash_history.sticky
```

Also make sure that `HISTSIZE` is at least `HISTFILESIZE` plus the number of lines in `~/.bash_history.sticky` plus the number of commands you execute in a long session, e.g.

```
HISTFILESIZE=1000
HISTSIZE=10000
```

If you want to ensure that the sticky history entries remain in memory without having a very large `HISTSIZE`, you can do it by manually trimming the history in `PROMPT_COMMAND` with `history -d`, but it's difficult to get right if you have `erasedups` in `HISTCONTROL`.

#### zsh

In `~/.zshrc`:

```
fc -RI ~/.zsh_history.sticky
```

Also make sure that `HISTSIZE` is at least `SAVEHIST` plus the number of lines in `~/.zsh_history.sticky` plus the number of commands you execute in a long session, e.g.

```
SAVEHIST=1000
HISTSIZE=10000
```

If you want to ensure that the sticky history entries remain in memory without having a very large `HISTSIZE`, you can do it by manually trimming the history in `precmd`, but it's cumbersome (zsh doesn't really support rewriting history, you have to `fc -W` into a temporary file and read back an edited version) and difficult to get right if you have the `hist_ignore_dups` or `hist_ignore_all_dups` option set.

Comment: Despite some little quirks you mentioned, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a cron job and a big number of lines in .*sh_history file

at the end of the day this cron entry runs (mine is set to 11 PM)

```
0 23 * * * cat /home/username/.bash_history >> /home/username/BIGHISTORY
```

If the sticky command happens to get out of the regular history scroll buffer, I can find it in BIGHISTORY file with a simple grep command and bring it back to the fold. I know this is not what you are looking for but this is the poor-man's version, that comes closest with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` (don't know about `zsh`), you can set

```
export HISTFILESIZE=-1
export HISTSIZE=-1
```

in your `.bashrc` to make your history forever. Not exactly what you're looking for, I know. For your favorite commands, I suggest to create aliases or functions, though.

Comment: I'd still like other commands in the history to expire, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Zsh, I retain history for a *long* time. The `HISTSIZE` is `20000`. (There are various settings involved in that, so I won’t list them here.) That buys me ~10 months worth. My history file (`~/.zhistory`) weighs in at 1.1 MiB and doesn’t make startup noticeably slower.

I commonly pull in working history from other terminals with `fc -R` (when multiples are open — always).

But to answer your question, I “stamp” the commands I really care about saving with a `# GOOD` comment on the end. These are often lengthy and hard-won, after a lot of experimenting. Some of them do end up becoming little reusable scripts, but a stamp is the quickest way to save it. With the long history, I can just do a history search for `# GOOD`, and usually come up with what I’m looking for pretty quickly.